# How does Revit Analysis Display "Show Contour" work?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I am not sure if "ShowContourLines" property of 
AnalysisDisplayColoredSurfaceSettings class in Revit works as expected.

I am expecting contours similar to isolines to be displayed but instead the outline
of the surface is highlighted.

Has any one got similar experience or know more about this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the `ShowContourLines` property, but here are some other samples using `AnalysisDisplayColoredSurfaceSettings` that may be of use:

- [Display Webcam Image on Building Element Face](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/display-webcam-image-on-building-element-face.html)
- [AVF Displays Intersections and Highlights Rooms](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/using-avf-to-display-intersections-and-highlight-rooms.html)
- [Apollonian Sphere Packing via Web Service and AVF](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/09/apollonian-packing-of-spheres-via-web-service-and-avf.html)
- [Intersect Solid Filter, AVF vs DirectShape Debugging](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/07/intersect-solid-filter-avf-and-directshape-for-debugging.html)